# How to run a query when the application is first deployed and then keep data for rest of the lifecycle

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-jdbc

I have a query where I'm getting column names from a DB. These column names won't change on a request or session basis. So, to avoid running useless queries on each request, I would like to run this query once when the application is deployed and then keep the results in a `List<String>` for rest of the lifecycle of the application (until its deployed again).

How can this be achieved so that I can use the final `List<String>` in my service layer?

If there is a better way to do this rather than tying running a query on deploy, then please suggest some other way.

Currently, I have this:

```
public List<String> fetchColNames (String tableName) {
    String query = "SELECT Upper(column_name) FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = ?";
        List<String> cols = getJdbcTemplate().query(query, new Object[] {tableName}, new RowMapper<String>() {
           public String mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
               return rs.getString(1);
           } 
        });
    return cols;
}
```

Comment: May be add list to application context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your method [Cachable](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotations-cacheable):

```
@Component
public class ColumnFetcher {
    @Cachable("columnNames")
    public List<String> fetchColNames (String tableName) {
        String query = "SELECT Upper(column_name) FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = ?";
            List<String> cols = getJdbcTemplate().query(query, new Object[] {tableName}, new RowMapper<String>() {
               public String mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                   return rs.getString(1);
               } 
            });
        return cols;
    } 
}
```

Of course you also have to [enable](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotation-enable) the cache annotations:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">
    <cache:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

Comment: This would work but maybe I'm not setting it correct or something is missing because I'm getting this error: `Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cacheManager'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `postconstruct` annoation on the method of a `configurable` bean, it will be executed when application is deployed.